# Mongo multiple $lookup and $group in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I am trying to "join" 3 different mongo collections in a query. So what I need is multiple `$lookup` and `$group` statements in a mongo aggregation.

My 3 collections look like this:

**users:** (Pseudocode)

```
{
  _id,
  username: String,
  group: <some group._id>
}
```

**groups:**

```
{
  _id,
  name: String,
  _parent: <another group._id>,
}
```

**lists:** (these are "itemlists" which are owned by a user):

```
{
  _id,
  name: String,
  userId: <some user._id>
}
```

So what I would like to do is, given some group id or `null` (for groups with no parent - groups on the highest level) - get all `groups` inside of this group, find all `users` in these groups and also their `lists`.

So in the end I would need something like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: someGroupId,
    name: someGroupName,
    type: "group",
    users: [
      {
        _id: someUserId,
        name: someUserName,
        type: "user",
        lists: [
          ... and the same again for the lists (type: "list")
        ]
      },
      ... another user
    ]
  },
  ... another group
]
```

I hope you understand what I mean!

What I have now (thanks to Simon Tretter and lots of research) - please don't mind the Meteor agnostic syntax, you get the idea:

```
Groups.aggregate([
    { $match: { _parent: groupId } },
    { $sort: { name: 1 } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'group',
            as: 'users'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$users",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'lists',
            localField: 'users._id',
            foreignField: 'userId',
            as: 'users.lists'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$users.lists",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { "users.lists": { $exists: false } },
                { "users.lists.supplier_id": supplierId }
            ]
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "users.lists.name": 1 } },
    {
        $project: {
            "name": 1,
            "type": { $literal: 'group' },
            "users._id": 1,
            "users.name": { $ifNull: ["$users.profile.company.name", "$users.username"] },
            "users.type": { $literal: 'user' },
            "users.lists._id": 1,
            "users.lists.name": 1,
            "users.lists.item_count": 1,
            "users.lists.type": { $literal: 'list' }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$users._id',
            name: { $first: "$users.name" },
            type: { $first: "$users.type" },
            children: {
                $push: "$users.lists"
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "users.name": 1 } },
    // until here I have one document per user, with their lists inside the "children" key - all good!
    // now I have to group the users inside their groups ...
    // NOT WORKING: returns completely wrong stuff
    { $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      type: { $first: "$type" },
      children: {
        $push: "$users"
      }
    } },
    { $sort: { name: 1 } }
]);
```

I hope someone can get my on the right track ... the best [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387603/mongodb-aggregate-nested-subdocuments) I could find didn't help me that much.

Comment: This data schema looks more like it was developed for a relational database than for MongoDB. Is changing it an option?

Comment: What especially would you change? appending the lists directly to each user?! In general: changing it completely is not really an option as this is an app in production. but the `groups` are a new feature so this could be changed. what data schema would you suggest?

Comment: I know you mention meteor but are you able to at least use a latest MongoDB 3.4.4 instance as the server? Reason being there are features that should help this. I presume one problem here is the hierarchical structure of "group" entries.

Comment: Hmm it would be possible but definitely takes some effort ... could you please be a bit more specific and tell me which new features you are talking about which should help?! :)

Comment: @PatrickDaVader The main case I'm thinking of depends on your "purpose" for "joining" this data. From that I mean if this is simply an exercise to return "joined" data, or whether there is an intent to "query" on certain conditions in the joined result. Your structure seems somewhat reminiscent of an "Object Graph", but it depends if you are searching the hierarchy or simply getting the "nested things" to current items. Could do with some clarity. Also please use the `@` thingy when responding to comments. It notifies us of your message, rather than making us come looking for it.

Comment: @NeilLunn What I am doing is basically building up a tree to manage certain aspects of my app. groups, users, lists ... so nope this is not simply an exercise, this is needed in the backend of my app. but if I understand you correctly yes I am "simply getting the nested things". fyi: I am using [this](https://ant.design/components/tree/) to then display the tree to a "admin user" to manage his groups, his customers (users) and their lists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Veeram and a tiny bit of tweaking I ended up with the following working code:

```
Groups.aggregate([
    { $match: { _parent: groupId } },
    { $sort: { name: 1 } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'group',
            as: 'users'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$users",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'lists',
            localField: 'userId',
            foreignField: 'users._id',
            as: 'users.lists'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$users.lists",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { "users.lists": { $exists: false } },
                { "users.lists.supplier_id": supplierId }
            ]
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "users.lists.name": 1 } },
    {
        $project: {
            "name": 1,
            "type": { $literal: 'group' },
            "users._id": 1,
            "users.name": { $ifNull: ["$users.profile.company.name", "$users.username"] },
            "users.type": { $literal: 'user' },
            "users.lists._id": 1,
            "users.lists.name": 1,
            "users.lists.item_count": 1,
            "users.lists.type": { $literal: 'list' }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: "$_id",
                name: "$name",
                type: "$type",
                user_id: "$users._id"
            },
            user_id: {
                $first: "$users._id"
            },
            name: {
                $first: "$users.name"
            },
            type: {
                $first: "$users.type"
            },
            children: {
                $push: "$users.lists"
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { name: 1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            name: {
                $first: "$_id.name"
            },
            type: {
                $first: "$_id.type"
            },
            children: {
                $push: {
                    _id: "$user_id",
                    name: "$name",
                    type: "$type",
                    children: "$children"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { name: 1 } }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.groups.aggregate(
[
  { $match: { _parent: groupId } },
  {
     $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'group',
            as: 'users'
     }
  },  
  { $unwind: "$users" },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'lists',
    localField: 'userId',
    foreignField: 'users._id',
    as: 'users.lists'
   }
  },
  { $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    groupname: { $first: "$name" },
    users: {
      $push: "$users"
   }
  } }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the `group` (`_id: {_id: "$_id", name: "$name", type: "$type", user_id: "$users._id" }`) information in the `$group` after your comment.

Something like

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: "$name",
            type: "$type",
            user_id: "$users._id"
        },
        name: {
            $first: "$users.name"
        },
        type: {
            $first: "$users.type"
        },
        children: {
            $push: "$users.lists"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        name: 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        name: {
            $first: "$_id.name"
        },
        type: {
            $first: "$_id.type"
        },
        users: {
            $push: {
                 _id:"$user_id",
                 name: "$name",
                 type: "$type",
                children: "$children"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try this asap and get back to you!

Comment: You are very close @Veeram but the userId gets lost in the process and I do not really understand why. I end up with something like this: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/4i9ifNdw) could you please kindly help again?! :) when I look at your code it makes sense to me so I don't really understand why the _id gets lost.

Comment: got it! please see my answer below! There are your 50 reps! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: maybe just one more thing @Veeram: Any idea how to get rid of the "empty" children when there e.g. are no lists of a user? (please see my pastebin link)

Comment: You are `$or` (`{ "users.lists": { $exists: false } }`) to keep the `users.lists` when they are not there. You can change your match to `{ $match: { "users.lists.supplier_id": supplierId   }  },`. This will drop the empty `users.lists`.

Comment: I thought so too! When I do what you suggested though, users without any lists are left out again and are not returned whatsoever. @Veeram

Comment: I don't think it is possible to remove `children/users` fields all together, but you can empty by adding `$redact` stage at the end. Something like `{
   "$redact": {
       "$cond": [{ $gt : ["$_id", null] },
         "$$DESCEND",
         "$$PRUNE"
     ]
   }
   }`